# File Reading Error: NoSuchElementException with Scanner

Tags: java, readfile, nosuchelementexception

I am relatively new to Java programming. Recently I decided to create a random system that stores, writes, and reads information on request. When reading a file I have already written with the program, I get the following errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at ReadFile.readFile(ReadFile.java:24)
at User.main(User.java:35)
```

I'm assuming this errors are a result of the User class calling on the ReadFile class, because the rest of the program works fine so far.

The User class that pertains:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class User 
{
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    System.out.println("User Information System:");
    System.out.println("Please type the full name of the person you wish to lookup.");
    input = user_input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("UIS currently has the following data on " + input + ":");

    if(input.equals("First Last"))
    {
        System.out.println("Opening Data on " + input + "...");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No Data found.");
    }
    if(input.equals("/create"))
    {
    CreateFile create = new CreateFile();
    create.openFile();
    create.addRecords();
    create.closeFile();
    }
    if(input.equals("/read"))
    {
    ReadFile read = new ReadFile();
    read.openFile();
    read.readFile();
    read.closeFile();
    }
  }
}
```

As well as the ReadFile class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ReadFile 
{
    static Scanner scanner;

    public void openFile()
    {
        try
        {
            scanner = new Scanner(new File("TestFile.txt"));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error reading file.");
        }
    }   
    public void readFile()
    {
        while(scanner.hasNext()) //Find a way to shorten this to a loop of printing whatever is in the file.
            {
            String a = scanner.nextLine();
            String b = scanner.next();
            String c = scanner.next();
            System.out.printf("%s %s %s\n", a,b,c);
            }
    }
    public void closeFile()
    {
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You call `nextLine` once and `next` twice in the loop. `hasNext` only guarantees you can call a next method once. Otherwise it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Sorry, it was originally scanner.next(); for each one, I forgot to change the nextLine back; would replacing hasNext be better than creating a better loop for calling several strings from the file?

Comment: You are trying to scan all lines in a file? Then do `Scanner.hasNextLine()` and **only** `scanner.nextLine()`, then extract out the values for a, b, and c. Maybe split the line on spaces or commas, for example.